# Program not returning elements of array

Tags: java, arrays

below is a program where I need to store String time and int datum as objects in an array and then print them out. This is what I am up to currently. I believe it is an issue with my recordEvent method.

```
class RecordEvents4 {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Recorder4 r1 = new Recorder4(100,100,"Wombat Detection");
      r1.recordEvent("10:53",20);
      r1.recordEvent("10:59",20);
      r1.recordEvent("11:05",20);
      r1.recordEvent("12:59",10);
      r1.recordEvent("13:59",10);
      r1.recordEvent("14:06",10);
      r1.printEvents();
   }
}

class Recorder4 {
   int xPos, yPos;
   String eventType;
   EventInformation[] event = new EventInformation[10];

   int xevent = 0;

   final int EVENT_MAX = 10;

   Recorder4(int xPos, int yPos, String eventType){
      this.xPos = xPos;
      this.yPos = yPos;
      this.eventType = eventType;
   }

   public void recordEvent(String time, int datum){
      /*for(int i = 0; i<event.length; i++){
         event[i] = new EventInformation(time, datum);
      }*/

      event[xevent] = new EventInformation(time, datum);

      xevent++; 
      if(xevent > EVENT_MAX){
         System.out.println("Event log overflow - terminating");
         System.exit(1);
      }
   }

   void printEvents(){       
      System.out.println("Record of " + eventType + " events at [" + xPos + "," + yPos + "]");  
      for(int i = 0; i < xevent; i++){
         System.out.println("Event number " + i + " was recorded at " + event[i] + " with datum = " + event[i]);
      }
   }
}

class EventInformation {
   String eventTime;
   int eventDatum;

   EventInformation(String eventTime, int eventDatum){
      this.eventTime = eventTime;
      this.eventDatum = eventDatum;      
   }
}
```

This is what it is outputting:

```
Record of Wombat Detection events at [100,100]
Event number 0 was recorded at EventInformation@15db9742 with datum = EventInformation@15db9742
Event number 1 was recorded at EventInformation@6d06d69c with datum = EventInformation@6d06d69c
Event number 2 was recorded at EventInformation@7852e922 with datum = EventInformation@7852e922
Event number 3 was recorded at EventInformation@4e25154f with datum = EventInformation@4e25154f
Event number 4 was recorded at EventInformation@70dea4e with datum = EventInformation@70dea4e
Event number 5 was recorded at EventInformation@5c647e05 with datum = EventInformation@5c647e05
```

This is what I am expecting:

```
Record of Wombat Detection events at [100,100] 
Event number 0 was recorded at 10:53 with datum = 20 
Event number 1 was recorded at 10:59 with datum = 20 
Event number 2 was recorded at 11:05 with datum = 20 
Event number 3 was recorded at 12:59 with datum = 10 
Event number 4 was recorded at 13:59 with datum = 10 
Event number 5 was recorded at 14:06 with datum = 10
```

I have been advised to use toString() but I am unsure whether I am even in the right direction with the recordEvent() where I am meant to be assigning the method arguments to to an EventInformation object, a reference to which is stored in an element of the event array.

Comment: You are printing the object instead of the specific properties. It should be `System.out.println("Event number " + i + " was recorded at " + event[i].eventTime + " with datum = " + event[i].eventDatum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively asking Java to print out an element of your events array. In your declaration of this array, you gave elements inside it the `EventInformation` type. Java, by default, obviously doesn't know how to print this, since you defined it yourself! To fix this, change your print statement:

```
    System.out.println("Event number " + i + " was recorded at " + event[i].eventTime + " with datum = " + event[i].eventDatum);
```

Now you are asking Java to print `eventTime` (a string) and `eventDatum` (an int). These are both things that Java knows how to print, since these are defined by Java itself.

Comment: Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `printEvents()` method should look like this:

```
void printEvents(){       
      System.out.println("Record of " + eventType + " events at [" + xPos + "," + yPos + "]");  
      for(int i = 0; i < xevent; i++){
         System.out.println("Event number " + i + " was recorded at " + event[i].eventTime + " with datum = " + event[i].eventDatum);
      }
   }
```

In your original code, you are trying to print the instance of `EventInformation` two times, instead of printing first the `eventTime` field and then `eventDatum`. Hence you get the defualt String representation of the instance, as defined in `Object`.

That, or write getter methods for `EventInformation`, if you'd like to, while setting the fields as `private`, which would probably be better practice, especially if there's more you'd like to do with the class later on.

EDIT: Same as Oliver-R said.

Comment: Thanks for helping :)